# Can ZFS resilvering be used effectively for backing up to an external drive?

Tags: backup, rsync, zfs

Suppose I currently use rsync to back up an internal drive periodically to an external drive. The external drive is usually stored offsite but is periodically brought over and plugged in via USB and then I manually go through the process of starting the rsync.

I'm new to ZFS but wondering if it would be possible to replace the above process with a setup in which the internal drive and the external drive are both part of a RAIDZ pool, so that as soon as I mount the external drive it starts resilvering. If so, how would resilvering compare to rsyncing in terms of performance? And in general, are there any downsides to such a setup?

Answer (score 5):

You could use re-silvering, but that's a terrible option. The failed drive will remain failed within ZFS until you mark it otherwise, so it's just as manual as your current process. You would have to make the external drive a mirror of the internal drive/array. Re-silvering's priority can not be controlled, so performance will be hit hard during the process.

It would be a better idea to snapshot, then `send` that snapshot to a file as backup. Restoring is just `receive` the file again. if you want an exact copy you can send from the snapshot then receive that to the backup drive. Backup is half of the intention of send/receive.

Comment: Why exactly is resilvering terrible for this?

Comment: little more detail added

Comment: ZFS resilvering is usually much slower than using send/receive. Plus with send/receive you can have more snapshots on the external drive than on your internal drive.